# Calculating cosine similarity across column in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am new to pandas and i have these 2 series.

`train['description_1']` and `train['description_2']` are series. They each contain a vector for each row.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
item3 = pd.concat([train['description_1'], train['description_2']], axis = 1)
cos_vec = item3.apply(cosine)
```

Exception would be `TypeError: ('cosine() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)', u'occurred at index description_1')`

Each element of train['description'] contains a vector.

I am expecting something like this

```
train_1       train_2
[1.0,2.0]     [2.0,3.0] 
[2.0,2.0]     [3.0,2.0] 


Output:

cos_sim 
x
y
```

Comment: Inside `apply`, `cosine` will take each column as input iteratively, so that's why it receives only one argument.

Comment: How do i resolve this then?

Answer (score 4):

You need:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

df = pd.DataFrame({'description_1':[0.1,0.32,0.3],
                   'description_2':[0.4,0.5,0.6]})


print (df)
   description_1  description_2
0           0.10            0.4
1           0.32            0.5
2           0.30            0.6

cos_vec = (1 - cosine(df["description_1"], df["description_2"]))
print (cos_vec)
0.962571458085
```

EDIT:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

df = pd.DataFrame({'description_1':[[1.0,2.0],[2.0,2.0]],
                   'description_2':[[2.0,3.0],[3.0,2.0]]})


print (df)
  description_1 description_2
0    [1.0, 2.0]    [2.0, 3.0]
1    [2.0, 2.0]    [3.0, 2.0]

cos_vec = df.apply(lambda x: (1 - cosine(x["description_1"], x["description_2"])), axis=1)
print (cos_vec)
0    0.992278
1    0.980581
dtype: float64
```

Comment: But i would have to do this for all elements in the series